# CodeIgniter cookies do not persist

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I am creating a login system and would like to store a username and a password (hashed and salted) to cookies. However, the cookies do not persist. The var_dump at the bottom displays the value of the cookie, but if I open a new page, the value is not there. Is

Below is my CodeIgniter code.

```
    function set_cookies() {
        $this->load->helper('cookie');

        $cookieData = array('name'   => 'username',
                            'value'  => $this->username,
                            'expire' => 86500,
                            'domain' => ".example.com",
                            'path'   => '/'
                        );
        $this->input->set_cookie($cookieData);

        $cookieData = array('name'   => 'password',
                            'value'  => $this->password,
                            'expire' => 86500,
                            'domain' => ".example.com",
                            'path'   => '/'
                        );
        $this->input->set_cookie($cookieData);

        var_dump($this->input->cookie("username"));
    }
```

Tried this to get the cookie back:
    public function testLogin() {
        var_dump($this->input); print "
";
        var_dump($this->input->cookie("username"));
    }

I have hit this problem long ago and never found a solution. Now on a new project, I have the same issue. Help is much, MUCH appreciated!

Comment: hi...instead of using var_dump...can you please use this function to check whether cokkie exist or not???
<code>
if(get_cookie('username'))
{

echo "Yes":
}
else{
echo "NO":
}
</code>

Comment: Don't save someone's password to a cookie, that's bad security juju.

Comment: @NishantLad - The boolean value of that expression is "false" when I vardump.

Comment: @Cryode - I usually don't; I'm still developing so I'm doing that for now until I figure out a better way to re-authenticate.

Comment: Okay...can u tell me what are the other values than these you are storing in cookie or session ????? i am afraid that you might have crossed the storing limit of codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Now I don't know that much about CodeIgniter but I guess it uses the PHP function setcookie. If so, you need to have expiry times that are UNIX timestamps in seconds since the epoch.

That means that "expire" in your case should be time() + 86500.

This is quite a common mistake. :)

Comment: CodeIgniter's set cookie functions add `time()` to the expire value that you set.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Session Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html).

This comes in handy for handeling login data.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);

$username = $this->session->userdata('username');
```

You will preferably add a MySQL database which CodeIgniter uses for storing data, instructed in given link. You can also set the duration in `config.php`.